# is it possible to generate a plaid public token without initializing Link?

Tags: plaid

I want to get the latest balances of accounts every time the user opens the page in our system. in order to do that, I need a public_token to request for access token and load accounts balance, but I couldn't find how to generate a public token without Link initialization. is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible except in the Sandbox test environment. Note that once you have an access token, you can save and re-use it for future calls.